# Move cursor from one EditText to another one if click any letter in field and same in remove letter than back privious filed?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Actually i have done that functionality but i get best approach and shortest way so please help me. This my code.I have used other way for that but occured some problem.if there is another good way to do it simply.So please help me.this is very essential part of my project for me. thanks in advance.

```
package osvin.com.edittext;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText edt_1,edt_2,edt_3,edt_4;
    StringBuilder sb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intialize();

        edt_1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (sb.length() == 0 & edt_1.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append(s);
                    edt_1.clearFocus();
                    edt_2.requestFocus();
                    edt_2.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

                if (sb.length() == 1) {
                    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
                    Log.e("beforeTextChanged", "beforeTextChanged----------1");
                }

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (sb.length() == 0) {

                    edt_1.requestFocus();
                    Log.e("afterTextChanged", "afterTextChanged----------1");
                }

            }
        });


        edt_2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(sb.length()==0&edt_2.length()==1)
                {
                    sb.append(s);
                    edt_2.clearFocus();
                    edt_3.requestFocus();
                    edt_3.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

                if(sb.length()==1){
                    sb.deleteCharAt(0);

                }

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(sb.length()==0){
                    edt_1.requestFocus();
                }

            }
        });

        edt_3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if(sb.length()==0&edt_3.length()==1){
                    sb.append(s);
                    edt_3.clearFocus();
                    edt_4.requestFocus();
                    edt_4.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

                if(sb.length()==1){
                    sb.deleteCharAt(0);

                }

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(sb.length()==0){
                    edt_2.requestFocus();

                }

            }
        });

        edt_4.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               if(sb.length()==0&edt_4.length()==1){
                    sb.append(s);
                    //edt_3.clearFocus();
                    edt_4.requestFocus();
                    edt_4.setCursorVisible(true);

                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

                if(sb.length()==1)
                {
                    sb.deleteCharAt(0);

                }

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(sb.length()==0){

                    edt_3.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void Intialize(){
        edt_1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_1);
        edt_2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_2);
        edt_3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_3);
        edt_4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_4);
        sb=new StringBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: `but occured some problem` can you explain more

Comment: Sir actually i have no idea to do that other way that is problem.